# Zeroclipboard hover issue

Tags: jquery, html, css, hover, zeroclipboard

I try to change the color of the entire `<tr>` on hover, however I can't get it to work with Zeroclipboard, also the cursor doesn't change, does anyone have an idea on how to get this to work?

(Atleast in my browser: Google Chrome Version 37.0.2062.124 m) with Zeroclipboard v2.1.6

My code below:

```
<html>
<head>
<style type="text/css">
.myTABLE { width: 100%; border-collapse: collapse; border: 1px solid black; background-color: lightgrey; }
.myTABLE td { border: 1px solid black; text-align: center; }
.myTABLE tr:hover { background-color: lightgreen; }
.mycopy.zeroclipboard-is-hover { background-color: lightgreen; cursor: hand; }
.mycopy.zeroclipboard-is-active { background-color: #46962B; }
</style>
</head>

<body>
<script type="text/javascript" src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="ZeroClipboard.js"></script>

<br><br><br>
<table class="myTABLE">
<tr><td>test</td><td class="mycopy">Copy 1</td><td>test</td></tr>
<tr><td>test</td><td class="mycopy">Copy 2</td><td>test</td></tr>
<tr><td>test</td><td class="mycopy">Copy 3</td><td>test</td></tr>
<tr><td>test</td><td class="mycopy">Copy 4</td><td>test</td></tr>
<tr><td>test</td><td class="mycopy">Copy 5</td><td>test</td></tr>
<tr><td>test</td><td class="mycopy">Copy 6</td><td>test</td></tr>
</table>

<script type="text/javascript">
var client = new ZeroClipboard( $('.mycopy') );

client.on( 'ready', function(event) {
// console.log( 'movie is loaded' );

client.on( 'copy', function(event) {
event.clipboardData.setData('text/plain', event.target.innerHTML);
} );

client.on( 'aftercopy', function(event) {
console.log('Copied text to clipboard: ' + event.data['text/plain']);
} );
} );

client.on( 'error', function(event) {
// console.log( 'ZeroClipboard error of type "' + event.name + '": ' + event.message );
ZeroClipboard.destroy();
} );
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2):

You forgot to enclose your javascript in the jQuery(document).ready(function() ... block.  Or the short version as in my code below - $(function() ...

Click the button to run the code.

```js
$(function() {
  ZeroClipboard.config({
    swfPath: "http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/zeroclipboard/2.1.6/ZeroClipboard.swf"
  });
  var client = new ZeroClipboard($('.mycopy'));

  client.on('ready', function(event) {

    console.log(event.target);
    // console.log( 'movie is loaded' );

    client.on('copy', function(event) {
      event.clipboardData.setData('text/plain', 'test');
    });

    client.on('aftercopy', function(event) {
      console.log('Copied text to clipboard: ' + event.data['text/plain']);
    });
  });

  client.on('error', function(event) {
    // console.log( 'ZeroClipboard error of type "' + event.name + '": ' + event.message );
    ZeroClipboard.destroy();
  });
});
```

```css
.myTABLE {
  width: 100%;
  border-collapse: collapse;
  border: 1px solid black;
  background-color: lightgrey;
}
.myTABLE td {
  border: 1px solid black;
  text-align: center;
}
.myTABLE tr:hover {
  background-color: lightgreen;
}
.mycopy.zeroclipboard-is-hover {
  background-color: lightgreen;
  cursor: hand;
}
.mycopy.zeroclipboard-is-active {
  background-color: #46962B;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/zeroclipboard/2.1.6/ZeroClipboard.js"></script>

<div class="mycopy">yo</div>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<table class="myTABLE">
  <tr>
    <td>test</td>
    <td class="mycopy">Copy 1</td>
    <td>test</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>test</td>
    <td class="mycopy">Copy 2</td>
    <td>test</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>test</td>
    <td class="mycopy">Copy 3</td>
    <td>test</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>test</td>
    <td class="mycopy">Copy 4</td>
    <td>test</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>test</td>
    <td class="mycopy">Copy 5</td>
    <td>test</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>test</td>
    <td class="mycopy">Copy 6</td>
    <td>test</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Thanks, however the hover still doesn't work on the entire <tr>, nor does the cursor change to the hand cursor.. and the clipboard part stopped working.. does it work for you? then it might be a browser issue.

Comment: whoops forgot to include the swf file (which you have to do if the file is not hosted locally in the same dir as the .js file). but... for some strange reason my mac is unable to run zeroclipboard on any jsfiddle that i've google.  not sure what's up.  does it work for you now?